# nls() : “Error singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates ”

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization, nls

I've read many similar questions but still couldn't find the answer.
Here is some data that I'm using to calibrate the equation below:

```
set.seed(100)
i <- sort(rexp(n = 100,rate = 0.01))
Tr <- sort(runif(n = 100,min = 5,max = 100))

k_start <- 3259
u_start <- 0.464
t0_start <- 38
n_start <- -1

i_test <- k_start*Tr^u_start * (5 + t0_start)^n_start

m <- nls(i~(k * Tr^u / (5+t0)^n), start = list(k = k_start, u = u_start,
                                               t0 = t0_start, n = n_start))
```

When I used `nlsLM` and the same error came up:

> Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates

For the start values, I tried to use the values from calibration in Python and still the same error occurs.

There's also another way to use that equation that is like this:
However, the result is the same error.

```
d_start <- 43

m <- nls(i ~ (k * Tr^u / d),
         start = list(k = k_start, u = u_start,d=d_start))
```

When I use only the numerator it works, but that's not what I need.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first nls, the right hand side depends on k, t0 and n only through
k / (5+t0)^n so it is over parameterized as one parameter could represent
their combined effect.  In the second nls the right hand side depends only
on k and d through k / d so again the problem has been over parameterized and
one parameter could represent their combined effect.

Getting rid of the excess parameters and getting the starting values using a linear model it converges.

```
fit.lm <- lm(log(i) ~ log(Tr))
co <- coef(fit.lm)
fit <- nls(i ~ k * Tr ^ u, start = list(k = exp(co[[1]]), u = co[[2]]))
fit
## Nonlinear regression model
##   model: i ~ k * Tr^u
##    data: parent.frame()
##         k         u 
## 0.0002139 3.0941602 
##  residual sum-of-squares: 79402
##
## Number of iterations to convergence: 43 
## Achieved convergence tolerance: 5.354e-06
```

### Reciprocal Model

Below we fit a "reciprocal model" which has the same number of parameters but a better fit as measured by the deviance which is the residual sum of squares.  A lower value means better fit.

```
# reciprocal model
fit.recip <- nls(i ~ 1/(a + b * log(Tr)), start = list(a = 1, b = 1))

deviance(fit)
## [1] 79402.17
deviance(fit.recip)
## [1] 25488.1
```

### Graphics

Below we plot both `fit` (red) and `fit.recip` (blue) models.

```
plot(i ~ Tr)
lines(fitted(fit) ~ Tr, col = "red")
lines(fitted(fit.recip) ~ Tr, col = "blue")
legend("topleft", legend = c("fit", "fit.recip"), lty = 1, col = c("red", "blue"))
```

(continued after plot)
[image: screenshot]

### plinear

Note that the `plinear` algorithm could be used as an alternative algorithm to fit the `fit` model above to avoid having to supply a starting value for k.  It also has the additional benefit that it requires substantially fewer iterations in this case (14 vs. 45).  With `plinear` the formula should omit the linear argument, k, as it is implied by the algorithm and will be reported as `.lin` .

```
nls(i ~ Tr ^ u, start = list(u = co[[2]]), algorithm = "plinear")
## Nonlinear regression model
##   model: i ~ Tr^u
##    data: parent.frame()
##         u      .lin 
## 3.0941725 0.0002139 
##  residual sum-of-squares: 79402
##
## Number of iterations to convergence: 14 
## Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.848e-06
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! I think it solves the problem that I'm having. However, if I want to use all the original parameter (even if it's too much), you don't think that there is a way to run `nls`?

Comment: There are an infinite number of solutions. You can pick arbitrary values for t0 and n, say, and then solve for k and u. Seems pretty meaningless though.  Have also added another model (blue line in plot) which has lower residual sum of squares and visually fits better too.